# Can somebody tell me what is wrong with this picture?

Tags: tomcat, ssl

I have a Tomcat 8 setup on my machine, I'm trying to setup SSL on it using a self-signed certificate I created that it's working for my Apache server, but when I try to browse it it says:

```
Error code: SSL_ERROR_NO_CYPHER_OVERLAP
```

This is how I have my Tomcat configured:

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
           maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
           SSLCipherSuite="ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-$
           keystoreFile="/usr/share/tomcat8/.keystore" 
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLSv1.2" 
           sslEnabledProtocol="TLSv1.2" />
```

I'm using the same SSLCipherSuite that works with Apache and same sslProtocol that works in Apache. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out, the problem is with this:

```
protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
```

Nio/Nio2 is to be used with certs created with keytool, as per certs created with openssl (like apache certs) are to be used with AprProtocol, so I installed the Apr library for Tomcat, but Tomcat kept saying it couldn't find it, so I created a new cert using keytool and I was able to have SSL enabled on my Tomcat.